# How to continue processing the license plate crop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I want to pre-process the patent plate and then enter an OCR.

In the part that I am, I have to do things in general, because I am working only with one image, but later they will be more and at different angles.

I am in the part where I insert filters, I wonder if the next part is to find the contours or straighten it (for this I am using hough transform).

Working [on colab:](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Pz4ebKrbc_bLU2TQjbK29pPXScupMxG7?usp=sharing)

```
!pip install pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pytesseract
plt.style.use('dark_background')

crop_img = cv2.imread('/content/0.png')

#IMG2GRAY
gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray)

#tresh
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
plt.imshow(thresh)

# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh,(5,5),0)
th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

plt.imshow(th3)
plt.show()
```

The output I have, which I think this is bad:

[image]

And this is the image:

[image]

And this is the output when I rotate the image with HoughTransform:

[image]

The final result should be something like this (but remember that I will use the same preprocessing for other images):

[image: Description]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a script in python to find the angle in which the license plate is rotated with and then rotating in the reverse order to deskew the license plate.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2

def rotate_image(image, angle):
    image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)
    result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return result

def compute_skew(src_img):

    if len(src_img.shape) == 3:
        h, w, _ = src_img.shape
    elif len(src_img.shape) == 2:
        h, w = src_img.shape
    else:
        print('upsupported image type')

    img = cv2.medianBlur(src_img, 3)

    edges = cv2.Canny(img,  threshold1 = 30,  threshold2 = 100, apertureSize = 3, L2gradient = True)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, math.pi/180, 30, minLineLength=w / 4.0, maxLineGap=h/4.0)
    angle = 0.0
    nlines = lines.size

    #print(nlines)
    cnt = 0
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[0]:
        ang = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)
        #print(ang)
        if math.fabs(ang) <= 30: # excluding extreme rotations
            angle += ang
            cnt += 1

    if cnt == 0:
        return 0.0
    return (angle / cnt)*180/math.pi

def deskew(src_img):
    return rotate_image(src_img, compute_skew(src_img))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import cv2
    img = cv2.imread('test.png')
    corrected_img = deskew(img)
```

Deskewed License Plate:

[image]

You can apply some post-processing to completely remove the padded region, but the angle correction is the most important part for any detector.

Gist link: https://gist.github.com/zabir-nabil/dfb78f584947ebdb9f29d39c9737b5c6

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful. Do you know what the next step would be to deliver the image as best as possible to the OCR?

Comment: A simple rotation is a good start. You can also find the four corners of the plate, map them to a rectangle that you know represents the right aspect ratio, and compute the affine transform that gives you that mapping. Then you can really deal with skew and other artifacts.